# Use the type of a template parameter as key for a map<"type", int>

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I mean to setup a map `m` where keys are variable types, and values are `int`s (I can change this later).
Then, in a templated function (which is not a class member), with a simplified example

```
template<typename T>
void foo(vector<T>& v) {
    int type_idx = m[T];   // How to use this?
    const int n = v.size();
    foo2(type_idx, n);
    return;
}
```

Can this be done?
How is the step for defining `m`, and how is the step for using it?

A rudimentary form is with

```
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        foo2(1, n);
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>) {
        foo2(2, n);
    } else if ...
    } else {
        myprintf("Not implemented for type %s", T);
    }
```

which corresponds to `m[int] = 1`, `m[double] = 2`, ...
But this is more cumbersome than the way I mean to implement (if possible).

As for the correct way of printing T, I can find something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`std::type_index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index). It is a wrapper of `std::type_info` that is intended to be used as key in a map. Objects of type `std::type_info` are generated using the `typeid` operator.

Then your function and map look like this:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

void foo2(int, int);

std::map<std::type_index, int> m{
    { typeid(int), 1 },
    { typeid(double), 2 },
};

template<typename T>
void foo(std::vector<T>& v)
{
    int type_idx = m[typeid(T)];

    const int n = v.size();
    foo2(type_idx, n);
}
```

Comment: I added one possible way to fill the map with values: using an initializer list. You can do that if you know the types needed in advance.